# jQuery vTicker on a generated list

Tags: javascript, jquery, vticker

Im having a little issue with something, i have a plugin that fetches my twitter feed which works great! however i want it to scroll through the

results, it is setting the vTickert CSS on the main container #twitterFeed but not doing anything else and im assuming maybe need to call it once its all loaded manualy in the script?

JS Plugin for twitter fetch / i also added the vticker in here as well

```
var twitterFetcher = function() {
    function v(a) {
        return a.replace(/<b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/b>/gi, function(a, f) {
            return f
        }).replace(/class=".*?"|data-query-source=".*?"|dir=".*?"|rel=".*?"/gi, "")
    }

    function l(a, c) {
        for (var f = [], g = new RegExp("(^| )" + c + "( |$)"), b = a.getElementsByTagName("*"), h = 0, e = b.length; h < e; h++) g.test(b[h].className) && f.push(b[h]);
        return f
    }
    var w = "",
        k = 20,
        x = !0,
        m = [],
        q = !1,
        n = !0,
        p = !0,
        r = null,
        s = !0,
        y = !0,
        t = null,
        z = !0;
    return {
        fetch: function(a) {
            void 0 === a.maxTweets && (a.maxTweets = 20);
            void 0 === a.enableLinks && (a.enableLinks = !0);
            void 0 === a.showUser && (a.showUser = !0);
            void 0 === a.showTime && (a.showTime = !0);
            void 0 === a.dateFunction && (a.dateFunction = "default");
            void 0 === a.showRetweet && (a.showRetweet = !0);
            void 0 === a.customCallback && (a.customCallback = null);
            void 0 === a.showInteraction && (a.showInteraction = !0);
            if (q) m.push(a);
            else {
                q = !0;
                w = a.domId;
                k = a.maxTweets;
                x = a.enableLinks;
                p = a.showUser;
                n = a.showTime;
                y = a.showRetweet;
                r = a.dateFunction;
                t = a.customCallback;
                z = a.showInteraction;
                var c = document.createElement("script");
                c.type = "text/javascript";
                c.src = "//cdn.syndication.twimg.com/widgets/timelines/" + a.id + "?&lang=en&callback=twitterFetcher.callback&suppress_response_codes=true&rnd=" + Math.random();
                document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(c)
            }
        },
        callback: function(a) {
            var c = document.createElement("div");
            c.innerHTML = a.body;
            "undefined" === typeof c.getElementsByClassName && (s = !1);
            a = [];
            var f = [],
                g = [],
                b = [],
                h = [],
                e = 0;
            if (s)
                for (c = c.getElementsByClassName("tweet"); e < c.length;) {
                    0 < c[e].getElementsByClassName("retweet-credit").length ? b.push(!0) : b.push(!1);
                    if (!b[e] || b[e] && y) a.push(c[e].getElementsByClassName("e-entry-title")[0]), h.push(c[e].getAttribute("data-tweet-id")), f.push(c[e].getElementsByClassName("p-author")[0]), g.push(c[e].getElementsByClassName("dt-updated")[0]);
                    e++
                } else
                    for (c = l(c, "tweet"); e < c.length;) a.push(l(c[e], "e-entry-title")[0]), h.push(c[e].getAttribute("data-tweet-id")), f.push(l(c[e], "p-author")[0]), g.push(l(c[e], "dt-updated")[0]), 0 < l(c[e], "retweet-credit").length ? b.push(!0) : b.push(!1), e++;
            a.length > k && (a.splice(k, a.length - k), f.splice(k,
                f.length - k), g.splice(k, g.length - k), b.splice(k, b.length - k));
            c = [];
            e = a.length;
            for (b = 0; b < e;) {
                if ("string" !== typeof r) {
                    var d = new Date(g[b].getAttribute("datetime").replace(/-/g, "/").replace("T", " ").split("+")[0]),
                        d = r(d);
                    g[b].setAttribute("aria-label", d);
                    if (a[b].innerText)
                        if (s) g[b].innerText = d;
                        else {
                            var u = document.createElement("p"),
                                A = document.createTextNode(d);
                            u.appendChild(A);
                            u.setAttribute("aria-label", d);
                            g[b] = u
                        } else g[b].textContent = d
                }
                d = "";
                x ? (p && (d += '<div class="user">' + v(f[b].innerHTML) + "</div>"), d +=
                    '<p class="tweet">' + v(a[b].innerHTML) + "</p>", n && (d += '<p class="timePosted">' + g[b].getAttribute("aria-label") + "</p>")) : a[b].innerText ? (p && (d += '<p class="user">' + f[b].innerText + "</p>"), d += '<p class="tweet">' + a[b].innerText + "</p>", n && (d += '<p class="timePosted">' + g[b].innerText + "</p>")) : (p && (d += '<p class="user">' + f[b].textContent + "</p>"), d += '<p class="tweet">' + a[b].textContent + "</p>", n && (d += '<p class="timePosted">' + g[b].textContent + "</p>"));
                z && (d += '<p class="interact"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to=' +
                    h[b] + '" class="twitter_reply_icon">Reply</a><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/retweet?tweet_id=' + h[b] + '" class="twitter_retweet_icon">Retweet</a><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/favorite?tweet_id=' + h[b] + '" class="twitter_fav_icon">Favorite</a></p>');
                c.push(d);
                b++
            }
            if (null == t) {
                a = c.length;
                f = 0;
                g = document.getElementById(w);
                for (h = "<ul>"; f < a;) h += "<li>" + c[f] + "</li>", f++;
                g.innerHTML = h + "</ul>"
            } else t(c);
            q = !1;
            0 < m.length && (twitterFetcher.fetch(m[0]), m.splice(0, 1))
        }
    }
}();

/*
  Vertical News Ticker 1.15

  Original by: Tadas Juozapaitis ( kasp3rito [eta] gmail (dot) com )
               http://www.jugbit.com/jquery-vticker-vertical-news-ticker/

  Forked/Modified by: Richard Hollis @richhollis - richhollis.co.uk
*/

(function($){

  var defaults = {
    speed: 700,
    pause: 4000,
    showItems: 2,
    mousePause: true,
    height: 189,
    animate: true,
    margin: 0,
    padding: 0,
    startPaused: false
  };

  var internal = { 

    moveUp: function(state, attribs) {    
      internal.animate(state, attribs, 'up');
    },

    moveDown: function(state, attribs){
      internal.animate(state, attribs, 'down');
    },

    animate: function(state, attribs, dir) {
      var height = state.itemHeight;
      var options = state.options;
      var el = state.element;
      var obj = el.children('ul');
      var selector = (dir === 'up') ? 'li:first' : 'li:last';

      el.trigger("vticker.beforeTick");

      var clone = obj.children(selector).clone(true);

      if(options.height > 0) height = obj.children('li:first').height();
      height += (options.margin) + (options.padding*2); // adjust for margins & padding

      if(dir==='down') obj.css('top', '-' + height + 'px').prepend(clone);

      if(attribs && attribs.animate) {
        if(state.animating) return;
        state.animating = true;
        var opts = (dir === 'up') ? {top: '-=' + height + 'px'} : {top: 0};
        obj.animate(opts, options.speed, function() {
            $(obj).children(selector).remove();
            $(obj).css('top', '0px');
            state.animating = false;
            el.trigger("vticker.afterTick");
          });
      } else {
        obj.children(selector).remove();
        obj.css('top', '0px');
        el.trigger("vticker.afterTick");
      }
      if(dir==='up') clone.appendTo(obj);
    },

    nextUsePause: function() {
      var state = $(this).data('state');
      var options = state.options;
      if(state.isPaused || state.itemCount < 2) return;
      methods.next.call( this, {animate:options.animate} );
    },

    startInterval: function() {
      var state = $(this).data('state');
      var options = state.options;
      var initThis = this;
      state.intervalId = setInterval(function(){ 
        internal.nextUsePause.call( initThis );
      }, options.pause);
    },

    stopInterval: function() {
      var state = $(this).data('state');
      if(!state) return;
      if(state.intervalId) clearInterval(state.intervalId);
      state.intervalId = undefined;
    },

    restartInterval: function() {
      internal.stopInterval.call(this);
      internal.startInterval.call(this);
    }
  };

  var methods = {

    init: function(options) {
      // if init called second time then stop first, then re-init
      methods.stop.call(this);
      // init
      var defaultsClone = jQuery.extend({}, defaults);
      var options = $.extend(defaultsClone, options);
      var el = $(this);
      var state = { 
        itemCount: el.children('ul').children('li').length,
        itemHeight: 0,
        itemMargin: 0,
        element: el,
        animating: false,
        options: options,
        isPaused: (options.startPaused) ? true : false,
        pausedByCode: false
      };
      $(this).data('state', state);

      el.css({overflow: 'hidden', position: 'relative'})
        .children('ul').css({position: 'absolute', margin: 0, padding: 0})
        .children('li').css({margin: options.margin, padding: options.padding});

      if(isNaN(options.height) || options.height === 0)
      {
        el.children('ul').children('li').each(function(){
          var current = $(this);
          if(current.height() > state.itemHeight)
            state.itemHeight = current.height();
        });
        // set the same height on all child elements
        el.children('ul').children('li').each(function(){
          var current = $(this);
          current.height(state.itemHeight);
        });
        // set element to total height
        var box = (options.margin) + (options.padding * 2);
        el.height(((state.itemHeight + box) * options.showItems) + options.margin);
      }
      else
      {
        // set the preferred height
        el.height(options.height);
      }

      var initThis = this;
      if(!options.startPaused) {
        internal.startInterval.call( initThis );
      }

      if(options.mousePause)
      {
        el.bind("mouseenter", function () {
          //if the automatic scroll is paused, don't change that.
          if (state.isPaused === true) return; 
          state.pausedByCode = true; 
          // stop interval
          internal.stopInterval.call( initThis );
          methods.pause.call( initThis, true );
        }).bind("mouseleave", function () {
          //if the automatic scroll is paused, don't change that.
          if (state.isPaused === true && !state.pausedByCode) return;
          state.pausedByCode = false; 
          methods.pause.call(initThis, false);
          // restart interval
          internal.startInterval.call( initThis );
        });
      }
    },

    pause: function(pauseState) {
      var state = $(this).data('state');
      if(!state) return undefined;
      if(state.itemCount < 2) return false;
      state.isPaused = pauseState;
      var el = state.element;
      if(pauseState) {
        $(this).addClass('paused');
        el.trigger("vticker.pause");
      }
      else {
        $(this).removeClass('paused');
        el.trigger("vticker.resume");
      }
    },

    next: function(attribs) { 
      var state = $(this).data('state');
      if(!state) return undefined;
      if(state.animating || state.itemCount < 2) return false;
      internal.restartInterval.call( this );
      internal.moveUp(state, attribs); 
    },

    prev: function(attribs) {
      var state = $(this).data('state');
      if(!state) return undefined;
      if(state.animating || state.itemCount < 2) return false;
      internal.restartInterval.call( this );
      internal.moveDown(state, attribs); 
    },

    stop: function() {
      var state = $(this).data('state');
      if(!state) return undefined;
      internal.stopInterval.call( this );
    },

    remove: function() {
      var state = $(this).data('state');
      if(!state) return undefined;
      internal.stopInterval.call( this );
      var el = state.element;
      el.unbind();
      el.remove();
    }
  };

  $.fn.vTicker = function( method ) {
    if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.vTicker' );
    }    
  };
})(jQuery);
```

JS im using to call everything

```
// Setup twitter feed
function dateFormatter(date) {
  return date.toString().split(' ')[1] + ' ' + date.getFullYear() % 100;
}
var twitterConfig = {
  "id": '489803450398433282',
  "domId": 'twitterFeed',
  "maxTweets": 6,
  "enableLinks": true,
  "dateFunction": dateFormatter
};
twitterFetcher.fetch(twitterConfig);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#twitterFeed').vTicker();
});
```

maybe i need to manually add in and call

```
$('#twitterFeed').vTicker();
```

within the plugin? its never going to be updated so dont mind it going directly in the code if need be

Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, solution was as follows:

```
// Setup twitter feed
function dateFormatter(date) {
  return date.toString().split(' ')[1] + ' ' + date.getFullYear() % 100;
}
var twitterConfig = {
  "id": '489803450398433282',
  "domId": 'twitterFeed',
  "maxTweets": 6,
  "enableLinks": true,
  "dateFunction": dateFormatter,
  "customCallback": handleTweets,
};

function handleTweets(tweets){
    var x = tweets.length;
    var n = 0;
    var element = document.getElementById('twitterFeed');
    var html = '<ul>';
    while(n < x) {
      html += '<li>' + tweets[n] + '</li>';
      n++;
    }
    html += '</ul>';
    element.innerHTML = html;
    $('#twitterFeed').vTicker();
}

twitterFetcher.fetch(twitterConfig);
```